# How to access react state of a page from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to write a chrome extension which could interact with the page which is a react-app. i am able to manipulate DOM by using `popup.js`.

Here is my popup.js

```js
document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  console.log(tab);

  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      files: ["scripts/script.js"],
    },
    (result) => {
      console.log("injection result :", result);
    }
  );
});
```

by the help of `script.js` i may reach any sort of element except the reacts state.

I have found a Q/A over here which helps to find __reactInternal$ here is the code.

```js
function FindReact(dom, traverseUp = 0) {
  const key = Object.keys(dom).find((key) => {
    return (
      key.startsWith("__reactFiber$") || // react 17+
      key.startsWith("__reactInternalInstance$")
    ); // react <17
  });
  const domFiber = dom[key];
  if (domFiber == null) return key;

  // react <16
  if (domFiber._currentElement) {
    let compFiber = domFiber._currentElement._owner;
    for (let i = 0; i < traverseUp; i++) {
      compFiber = compFiber._currentElement._owner;
    }
    return compFiber._instance;
  }

  // react 16+
  const GetCompFiber = (fiber) => {
    //return fiber._debugOwner; // this also works, but is __DEV__ only
    let parentFiber = fiber.return;
    while (typeof parentFiber.type == "string") {
      parentFiber = parentFiber.return;
    }
    return parentFiber;
  };
  let compFiber = GetCompFiber(domFiber);
  for (let i = 0; i < traverseUp; i++) {
    compFiber = GetCompFiber(compFiber);
  }
  return compFiber.stateNode;
}
```

Even if the code above works well over the console, i cant use it in my `script.js`. what could be the reason? How can i access reacts state by the help of a chrome-extesion.

Note: i dont want to use reactdevtool. i am trying to write an end-user extension. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Add `world: 'MAIN'` to executeScript config.

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much. but i haven't seen this attribute before. i will inspect the executeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with

```js
$r.state
```

I'll be adding the example visually.

To view state data this plugin will come in handy: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVLBu.jpg)